# Java 11 - Replace Spring @PostConstruct with afterPropertiesSet or using initMethod

Tags: java, spring, java-11, spring-bean, postconstruct

I'm using spring applications which sometimes uses `@PostConstruct` for setup in code and tests

It seems that annotation will be excluded from [Java 11](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy):

> Note that both @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations are part of Java EE. And since Java EE has been deprecated in Java 9 and removed in Java 11 we have to add an additional dependency to use these annotations

[Article](https://better-coding.com/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-alternatives-in-java-9/) suggest replacing all `@PostConstruct` with `afterPropertiesSet` method

> I recommend you to change implementation from @PostConstruct annotation to implement org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean interface.

Can I blindly replace it in all cases? or are there other considerations?

**EDIT**

As @JBNizet suggested, this maybe not a must or needed, as [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle) doc suggest the opposite

> We recommend that **you do not use the InitializingBean** interface, because it **unnecessarily couples the code to Spring**. Alternatively, **we suggest using the @PostConstruct** annotation or specifying a POJO initialization method.

**EDIT 2**

Another option is using `initMethod`:

> With Java configuration, you can use the initMethod attribute of @Bean
>
> ```
> @Bean(initMethod = "init")
> public BeanOne beanOne() {
>     return new BeanOne();
> }
> ```

Comment: You should just ignore this advice, and keep using PostConstruct. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle

Comment: @JBNizet Do you know where's the confusion come from ? there's another reference https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#java

Comment: What "confusion" are you talking about? Neither Micronaut nor Spring are confused. They both use PostConstruct. It's not in the JDK anymore, so what? You add  the necessary dependency, as you do for basically everything else.

Comment: @JBNizet can you answer? There's still an advantages of smaller dependency and size

Comment: It seems likely that Spring will provide their own `PostConstruct` annotation if and when it is removed from Java.  That is assuming that Spring does not already provide their own PostConstruct annotation

Answer (score 5):

Spring uses `jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct`. As a contributor in `spring-cloud-kubernetes`, I have used it and included it in that project numerous times. As a matter of fact we favor *dropping* `InitializingBean`.

Answer (score 0):

Ref https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations

> Like @Resource, the @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotation types were a part of the standard Java libraries from JDK 6 to 8. However, the entire javax.annotation package got separated from the core Java modules in JDK 9 and eventually removed in JDK 11. If needed, the javax.annotation-api artifact needs to be obtained via Maven Central now, **simply to be added to the application’s classpath like any other library.**