# Spring bean creation lifecycle : Why having multiple interaction points?

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning spring and I'm stuck with the bean lifecycle !

When creating a bean, spring gives us several maners to interact with it. We can use one or all of :

`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`
`BeanPostProcessor#postProcessBeforeInitialization`
`@PostConstruct`
`InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet`
`@Bean#initMethod`
`BeanPostProcessor#postProcessAfterInitialization`

***Spring calls them in the order above***

My question is : why all these points of interaction ? and when to use each of them (the use case) ?

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559332/java-11-replace-spring-postconstruct-with-afterpropertiesset-or-using-initmet

Comment: @user7294900 yeh related but it did'nt answer my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and a `BeanPostProcessor` are quite different beast and also apply to different things.

A `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` will operate on the metadata for a bean (I like to call it the recipe) and will post process that. A well know example is the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` which will inject/replace all `@Value` in configuration with the value. A `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` operates on the metadata and thus before any bean has been created.

The `BeanPostProcessor` can be applied to a bean and can even replace a bean. Spring AOP uses this quite a lot. An example is the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor`, when a bean has been created it will pass through this `BeanPostProcessor` and when it is annotated with `@Persistence` the bean will be replaced by a proxy. This proxy adds exception translation (i.e. it will convert `JpaException` and `SQLException` to the Spring `DataAccessException`). This is done in a `BeanPostProcessor. And can be be done before the init-callbacks are called (the` postProcessBeforeInitialization`or after they have been called the`postProcessAfterInitialization`). The` PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor`will run in the`postProcessAfterInitialization` as it needs to be certain the bean has been initialized.

The `ServletContextAwareProcessor` will run right after the object has been created to inject the `ServletContext` as early as possible as the initializing of a bean might depend on it.

The 3 callbacks for initializing a bean are more or less the same but are called in sequence because they have been included in later versions. It starter with only an interface `InitializingBean` and `init-method` in xml (later also added to `@Bean` and the annotation support was added when annotations became a thing.

You need init methods to initialize a bean, you might want to check if all properties have been set (like a required datasource) or you might want to start something. A `DataSource` (especially a connection pool) is a good example to initialize. After all dependencies have been injected you want to start the pool so it will open the connections. Now as you probably cannot modify the code you want to use the `init-method` if you control the code you probably want to add `@PostConstruct`. If you are writing an framework that depends on Spring I would use the `InitializingBean`.

Next to those 3 init methods you also have the destruction counter-parts. The `DisposableBean` interface (and `destroy-method`) and the `@PreDestroy` annotation. Again when you stop your application you also want to close the connections in your connection pool and you want to probably call the `close` method on the `DataSource`. A perfect sample of a destruction callback.